# Difference between a control in a frame and a control not in a frame

Tags: vba

I am writing a Excel VBA program that examines VBA forms and converts them to HTML forms.  Most of it works, but I need to know how to tell if a VBA control is within a frame or not.  Because when I use absolute positioning in HTML, if (for example) the left attribute of a control in a frame needs the left attribute of the frame added to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily a frame, it can be any control that allows nested controls.

There are several ways to deal with it:

- Recursively add all `.Parent.Left` until the last `.Parent` is the form.
- Translate to HTML using nested blocks too, so that you don't need to add anything.

Comment: thanks GSerg..  I did a "? userform22.textbox19.parent.name" and it gave me "Frame1" which is what I want to know.

Comment: @LittleNorm That is a wrong approach. You should not rely on controls names. If you want to keep it simple and only support frames (and only one nesting level deep), you can check if `TypeOf textbox19.parent Is Frame`.